# Can two vim instances, one opening read-only, use the same swap file?

Tags: vim

I am trying to determine if a vim read-only instance can open a file, to detect changes.

I am developing a method of forging a [minimap](http://www.sublimetext.com/)-style functionality in VIM running in Konsole (KDE terminal emulator). I am having trouble syncing the two views. My line of thinking is that I might use a marker, but I need the map view to have access to the main view's markers. Is there a way to open an already-open file with the -R flag (readonly) but have it read the existing swap file to be notified of new markers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see a way to do this, and tried using a simple text file and two processes trying to edit the same file, with one Vim process invoked with -R.

Using gVim -- never tried with command line vim -- it is notified when a change takes place, but not because another vim process made the change. In other words, CVS might update a file I am editing, and I'm asked whether to ignore or reload, but two vim processes did not have that file open.

I did some more work with this, and using -R and 7.2.330 and I was able to edit one file regularly and the same file using vim -R. When I wrote out the file with a change, the other file did not see the change. gVim did see the change when made.